# Error displaying some PDFs with OpenViewerFX

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, openviewerfx

I am using **OpenViewerFX** (JPedal) to display **PDF files** in a **JavaFX** application. Some files are displayed well, others only show not printable characters (in documents created by myself and also documents from other people). 
See for example this one:

[image: Display error]

This is my code:

```
private final PdfDecoderFX pdf = new PdfDecoderFX();
private Group group;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 400, 400);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    group = new Group();
    group.getChildren().add(pdf);

    bp.setCenter(group);


    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        try {
            pdf.openPdfFile("D:\\Dokument1.pdf");
            decodePage();
        } catch (PdfException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}

private void decodePage() {

    try {
        pdf.setPageParameters(2.0f, 0);
        pdf.decodePage(1);
        pdf.waitForDecodingToFinish();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The PDF file was created from a Word document with **Adobe PDF** printer. I used the **standard font** and **only standard characters**. I tested several settings when creating the file, including

- Compatibility "PDF 1.3" to "PDF 1.7"
- Enable/Disable web optimization
- Include all fonts
- Include Open-Type fonts

but always the same result.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a font issue to me. The debugging output helped me in the past - at least I saw some error message in there. I'm not quite sure what the correct option was but try the following:

1. Did you try to enable jpedal logging?

> ```
> //debug code
> LogWriter.log_name="/yourpath/log.txt";
> LogWriter.setupLogFile(true,0,"1.0","v",false);
> ```

2. What does the `org.jpedal.PdfDecoder.getPageDecodeStatus(int type)`state where type is any value Defined in `org.jpedal.parser.DecodeStatus`
3. We use a patched version of the ViewerFX - can you try that [one](https://github.com/Lonzak/OpenViewerFX)?
4. Are you sure you specified the correct path to the fonts?
   To add a whole directory of fonts via JVM flag set the JVM flag `-Dorg.jpedal.fontdirs=dirList` where dirList is a comma-separated list of possible directories.
5. What is your OS? Windows or Linx?
6. Did you also try the `-Dorg.jpedal.inclusiveLogFilter= "memory,error"`JVM option?
7. Try to set `-Dverbose=true`
8. Call `GUI.debugFX=true;` see [here](https://github.com/Lonzak/OpenViewerFX/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jpedal/examples/viewer/gui/GUI.java).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I have not tried logging yet. I'll test it at monday when I'm back at work and give you response.

Comment: I tested your suggestions and here are my results:
**1.** Logging says "unknown font" for one document which does not work, but not for all
**2.** Could not test because "org.jpedal.parser.DecodeStatus" does not exist (also not in any other package)
**3.** Using this version did not change anything
**4.** Adding the JVM flag did not help (should not be required at all, because I embedded the fonts in the PDF)
**5.** Does not work on both Windows or Linux
**6.** Program does not start with this option (main class memory,error could not be found or loaded)

Comment: **7.** Added this option, seems to do nothing
**8.** --> compiler error "the final field GUI.debugFx cannot be assigned"

Comment: I tested IcePDF and it works for all tested PDF files, will switch to this.
Thanks for the useful tips anyway, +1